# Bash FIFOs not working as expected - how to debug it

Tags: bash

I was given the following assignment. We have a prebuilt GUI in a binary form, kept in `$GAME_BIN`. I have to write a script which connects the GUI with the AI engine. This is my code, which is pretty self descriptive. We have in this case: `GAME_BIN=./sredniowiecze_gui`, `ai1=./idle_ai.sh`, `ai2=./idle_ai.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# arguments parsing and setting $args - not posting this here

gui_outpipe=$(mktemp -u)
gui_inpipe=$(mktemp -u)
ai1_outpipe=$(mktemp -u)
ai1_inpipe=$(mktemp -u)
ai2_outpipe=$(mktemp -u)
ai2_inpipe=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $gui_outpipe $gui_inpipe $ai1_outpipe $ai1_inpipe $ai2_inpipe $ai2_outpipe

printinit 1 > $ai1_inpipe &
printinit 2 > $ai2_inpipe &
$GAME_BIN $args < $gui_inpipe &
$ai1 < $ai1_inpipe > $ai1_outpipe &
$ai1 < $ai2_inpipe > $ai2_outpipe &
while true; do
    echo "Started the loop"
    while true; do
        read line < $ai1_outpipe || echo "Nothing read"
        echo $line
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "$line" > $gui_inpipe
            echo "$line" > $ai2_inpipe
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
    while true; do
        read line < $ai2_outpipe || echo "nothing read"
        echo $line
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "$line" > $gui_inpipe
            echo "$line" > $ai2_inpipe
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
done

wait
```

I created a simple idle AI contained in `idle_ai.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    echo END_TURN
done
```

Then the END_TURN message from the GUI is not received at all. On the other hand, the second `END_TURN` in line `(*)` is not received by the script. If I use my own C-written AI - very long code, not posting it here, no information from the AI is received in the second run of the while loop

I have absolutely no idea how to debug it.

Since I'm not eager to run binaries unsandboxed, I'm calling the script by `firejail ./game.sh [irrelevant parameters]`

**EDIT** after adding `set -x` the output is

```
INIT 10 3 1 1 1 3 9
+ [[ -n ./idle_ai.sh ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ -n ./idle_ai.sh ]]
+ printinit 1
+ ./sredniowiecze_gui -human2
+ true
+ echo 'Started the loop'
Started the loop
+ true
+ read line
+ ./idle_ai.sh
+ echo 'INIT 10 3 1 1 1 3 9'
+ echo END_TURN
END_TURN
+ [[ -n END_TURN ]]
+ echo END_TURN
+ [[ END_TURN == \E\N\D\_\T\U\R\N ]]
+ break
+ true
+ read line
+ echo MOVE 5 9 5 8
MOVE 5 9 5 8
+ [[ -n MOVE 5 9 5 8 ]]
+ echo 'MOVE 5 9 5 8'
```

In AI vs AI mode:

```
INIT 10 3 1 1 1 3 9
+ [[ -n ./idle_ai.sh ]]
+ [[ -n ./idle_ai.sh ]]
+ printinit 1
+ printinit 2
+ ./sredniowiecze_gui
+ ./idle_ai.sh
+ true
+ echo 'Started the loop'
Started the loop
+ echo 'INIT 10 3 1 1 1 3 9'
+ true
+ read line
+ ./idle_ai.sh
+ echo 'INIT 10 3 2 1 1 3 9'
+ echo END_TURN
END_TURN
+ [[ -n END_TURN ]]
+ echo END_TURN
+ echo END_TURN
+ [[ END_TURN == \E\N\D\_\T\U\R\N ]]
+ break
+ sleep 1
+ true
+ read line
+ echo END_TURN
END_TURN
+ [[ -n END_TURN ]]
+ echo END_TURN
+ echo END_TURN
+ [[ END_TURN == \E\N\D\_\T\U\R\N ]]
+ break
+ sleep 1
+ true
+ echo 'Started the loop'
Started the loop
+ true
+ read line
```

**EDIT2**
I did the suggested changes, now my code is:

```
printinit 1 > $ai1_inpipe &
printinit 2 > $ai2_inpipe &
$GAME_BIN $args < $gui_inpipe &
$ai1 < $ai1_inpipe > $ai1_outpipe &
echo $!
$ai2 < $ai2_inpipe > $ai2_outpipe &
echo $!
while true; do
    echo "Started the loop"
    while true; do
        read -u3 line || echo "Nothing read"
        echo $line
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "$line" > $gui_inpipe
            echo "$line" > $ai2_inpipe
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
    while true; do
        read -u4 line || echo "nothing read"
        echo $line
        if [[ $line ]]; then
            echo "$line" > $gui_inpipe
            echo "$line" > $ai1_inpipe
            if [[ "$line" == "END_TURN" ]]; then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    sleep $turndelay
done 3<$ai1_outpipe 4<$ai2_outpipe
```

And now the script gets stuck on the `echo "$line" > $ai1_inpipe` line, although the `$ai2` process is still running.

**EDIT3**. Now the log with `set -x` is

```
INIT 10 3 1 1 1 3 9
+ [[ -n ./idle_ai.sh ]]
+ [[ -n ./idle_ai.sh ]]
+ printinit 1
+ printinit 2
+ ./sredniowiecze_gui
+ echo 26
26
+ ./idle_ai.sh
+ echo 'INIT 10 3 1 1 1 3 9'
+ echo 27
27
+ ./idle_ai.sh
+ echo 'INIT 10 3 2 1 1 3 9'
+ true
+ echo 'Started the loop'
Started the loop
+ true
+ read -u3 line
+ echo END_TURN
END_TURN
+ [[ -n END_TURN ]]
+ echo END_TURN
+ echo END_TURN
+ [[ END_TURN == \E\N\D\_\T\U\R\N ]]
+ break
+ sleep 1
+ true
+ read -u4 line
+ echo END_TURN
END_TURN
+ [[ -n END_TURN ]]
+ echo END_TURN
+ echo END_TURN
```

If you add an `echo FOO` before and after the call, like this:

```
            echo FOO
            echo "$line" > $ai1_inpipe
            echo BAR
```

then `echo FOO` is executed and `echo BAR` not.

Comment: You are not showing us that your variable values are safe being unquoted. You are even running commands we don't know (`$GAME_BIN`? `$ai1`???). But I think the whole problem is that you are backgrounding stuff without waiting for that stuff to finish before starting the game engine or something like that...  In any case you need to give us the name of your scripts and the way you call them at minimal. Since we can't be sure you are actually running this with bash...

Comment: Well, the commands are `GAME_BIN=./sredniowiecze_gui`, `ai1=./idle_ai.sh`. Should I provide something else?

Comment: The first lines of your script and how you call it. Also, please put those pieces of information in the question, not just the comments :)

Comment: @Mr. Llama, that is not true. [[ $line ]] is perfectly valid.

Comment: Added the information

Comment: Cool edit, now we need to know how you are launching your script to be able to tell you how you can debug it. (but it basically goes down to adding `set -x` to know what is going to be executed)

Comment: I've already written that, see the `firejail` line

Comment: Well it was not there when I first posted that :P. Assuming `firejail` (which I never used) does not cause any mess, please post the output of your script after adding the `set -x` line before the loop. Or only what you expect to be the relevant part of it. We want to know why you don't catch the `END_LINE`

Comment: Well, your GUI is writing out a MOVE command and your script receives and handles it.  Sounds like the problem may be with your GUI not outputting what you expect, not your shell script.

Comment: That or you didn't paste what comes next :)

Comment: There's nothing else. But when I write the same things into the GUI manually, I get the right output

Comment: Oh, found another symptom. When I run the GUI in a AI vs AI mode with the same END_TURN AI, then the problem appears in the second run of the loop. I'm uploading the output with `set -x`

Comment: And, for the AI vs AI mode the code is slightly different, so I updated it in the OP. But the changes are cosmetic.

Comment: I think I got it... You're using `read < input`, which sucks all the input only uses the first line! Instead of doing that, you should have `read` read from open file descriptors :)

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"

Comment: I mean nothing happens. I'm uploading the log with `set -x`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or http://sscce.org/ -- a good code sample contains **only the bare minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce an issue**. Creating three pipelines when you only need one to reproduce an issue -> way more complexity than appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: There was one, but new issues arose. I want to leave the original code so that people with similar problem can find the answer. Or maybe I should create a separate question for the new problem?

Comment: New problem is the same problem. Instead of `echo > fifoname` you need to echo to an open `fd`. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `read < input`, which sucks all the input and only uses the first line.
Instead of doing that, you should have `read` read from open file descriptors, like this:

**EDIT**: Same thing with writing to the fifo files with `echo`

```
while true; do
echo "Started the loop"
while true; do
    read -u3 line || echo "Nothing read"
    ...
        echo "$line" >&5
        echo "$line" >&6
    ...
done
sleep $turndelay
while true; do
    read -u4 line || echo "nothing read"
    ...
        echo "$line" >&5
        echo "$line" >&7
    ...
sleep $turndelay
done 3<$ai1_outpipe 4<$ai2_outpipe 5>$gui_inpipe 6>$ai2_inpipe 7>$ai1_inpipe
```

See these links for more help on the topic:

- [BashGuide Named pipes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NamedPipes)
- [BashFAQ 085](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/085)

Comment: Hell, I guess that's that !! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to simply call the descriptors by name, something like `read --fd=$gui_inpipe line`?

Comment: No, I think `fd` can only be a number, sorry. and I don't think `--fd` exists, at least not on my system. The closest to what you want is this: `read -u $gui_in` and `done {gui_in}<$gui_inpipe` (or you can set the values yourself instead of automatically through that `{var}<in` syntax)

Comment: @Camusensei, to be clear, that can only be done on bash 4.1 or newer; `<$fd_num` wasn't valid syntax in 3.x (or 4.0), and neither was `{var}<in`.

Comment: ...btw, `read -u "$fd_num"` does allow a file descriptor to be specified by number, and works on older versions of bash than `<$fd_num` does, making it an equivalent to the `--fd` that @marmistrz asked for.

Comment: Well, if he/she want to use `read -u "$fd_num"`, he/she will also want to fill the fd by using `<$fd_num`... So it all boils down to which version of bash he/she is using. Thanks for the insight about `{var}<in`, I only learned about it recently and never checked when it appeared. But bash 4 is already old now, so everybody should have it :P

Comment: Oof, I meant `<&$fd_num` earlier. Almost tempted to remove (and maybe fix and readd?) my old comments.

Comment: @Camusensei, ...unfortunately, Apple refuses to agree to the GPLv3 as used by Bash 4, so they still ship bash 3.x, making portability caveats still relevant.

Comment: If you want to remove your old comments, I'll remove my answers to your comments so don't worry about the comment flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still don't understand why writing doesn't work as expected with my code and does, when I use a file descriptor. Isn't a file descriptor just an alias?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity (and because I'm not able to explain it in another way), let's assume it is an alias, but an alias that is created when opened and deleted when closed. So it only exists while the command that created it is running. Also, a pipe needs both input and output to be opened to exist. If one part is closed, the other part is useless. You should click links in my answer for more precise information on the topic